# puppeteer header and footertemplate doesnt work

Tags: css, pdf, puppeteer

This is my code for creating the pdf. Everything works great except the footer and header doesn't work. They are there (i think) but not visible. I have tried with displayHeaderFooter: true but all that makes is a date stamp in the header and some broken html code in the footer (as last picture).

```
async function createListenPdf(html, header, footer) {
try {
    var jobId = uuidv4();

    this.browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    var viewport = {
        width:1165,
        height:1200
    }
    page.setViewport(viewport);
    page.on("console", msg => {
        for (let i = 0; i < msg.args.length; ++i) {
            console.log(`${jobId} - From page. Arg ${i}: ${msg.args[i]}`);
        }
    });

    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });   

    await page.emulateMedia('screen');

    console.log("Header footer");
    var buffer = await page.pdf({
         printBackground: true,         
         footerTemplate: "<div style='width: 200px; background-color: #4286f4; position: relative; position: absolute; top:0;'>Hej</div>",
         headerTemplate: "<div style='width: 200px; background-color: #4286f4; position: relative; position: absolute; bottom: 0;'>Footer</div>",
         //displayHeaderFooter: true, 
         margin:{
             top: "100px",
             bottom: "100px"
         }
    });

    console.log(`${jobId} - Done. Will return the stream`);
    return buffer;
}
finally {
    if (this.browser) {
        console.log(`${jobId} - Closing browser`);
        this.browser.close();
    }
}
 }
```

[image]

As you can see i somehow got a footer with some grey area (i don't know why its grey). When i enable displayHeaderFooter: true in the options it looks like this:

[image]

Has anyone managed to create a pdf with puppeteer using html with header and footer? 
Here in their API description its seems pretty obvious but it really doesn't work.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.3.0/docs/api.md

Comment: Please try with `headerTemplate: '<span style="font-size: 30px; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: black; color: white; margin: 20px;">Header 1</span>',
            footerTemplate: '<span style="font-size: 30px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red; color:black; margin: 20px;">Footer</span>',` and let me know your feedback

Comment: i get the same result as above :(

Comment: Please make sure you are using latest version, I have tested this before posting

Comment: thats it!! I was somehow using 0.13 when i should be using 1.13!! Thank u! :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please try the following templates:

```
headerTemplate: '<span style="font-size: 30px; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: black; color: white; margin: 20px;">Header 1</span>',
footerTemplate: '<span style="font-size: 30px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red; color:black; margin: 20px;">Footer</span>'
```

Not all styling properties are supported, you should avoid using `position`, `top`, `bottom`.

Also make sure you are on the latest version of `puppeteer`.

Comment: It prints, but the footer and header on next page goes behind the page content. Any workaround for that? (z-index didn't work)

Answer (score 15):

Just bumped into the issue.

My observations about `headerTemplate`/`footerTemplate` are the following:

1. At least the `font-size` has to be specified (it's set to 1px by default, which is *very small*):

```
headerTemplate: '<span style="font-size: 10px"> <span class="pageNumber"></span>/<span class="totalPages"></span></span>',
```

2. *top/bottom margin* must be defined to set space for the header/footer
3. Some CSS properties indeed don't work. I didn't have any success with `background-color`, but maybe it's because the background isn't painted for these sections.
4. No asynchronous code (that would require an HTTP request) is allowed, such as calling a CSS stylesheet, loading an image or a font.
   Consequently, CSS have to be inlined. To add an image, it can be *base-64* encoded, as shown below. Concerning the fonts, we would need to rely on what is expected to be installed on the *Puppeteer* server I guess. Maybe there's a way to also embed it in *base-64*, I didn't try.

```
const printPDF = async () => {
    const footer = `<footer style="margin: auto; width: 40%">
            <img style="float: left; marginRight: 8px; marginLeft: 36px; width: 25%" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...09Yv//Z" alt="Pivohub" />
            <p style="font-family: arial; float: right; width: 55%; color: red; margin-top: 24px; font-size: 10px">
                <b>My footer</b>
            </p>
        </footer>`

    const content = `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
                <style type="text/css">
                    body { backgroundColor: "red" }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </body>
        </html>`

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setContent(content, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" })
    const buffer = await page.pdf({
        format: "A4",
        displayHeaderFooter: true,
        headerTemplate: '<span style="font-size: 10px"> <span class="pageNumber"></span> of <span class="totalPages"></span></span>',
        footerTemplate: footer,
        margin: { top: "100px", bottom: "200px" },
        printBackground: true,
    })
}
```

*In this sample, the base 64 image was truncated. An image can be converted thanks to an online base-64 converter such as https://www.base64-image.de*.

Comment: for background, I had to add this style along with the header/footer content: html,body,div{-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact}

Comment: any idea how to have header/footer without margin?

Comment: @KishorTiwari Not sure about which margins you're speaking about

Comment: It prints, but the footer and header on next page goes behind the page content. Any workaround for that? (z-index didn't work)

Comment: @Srk95 Not sure, I always managed to have high enough top/bottom margins to prevent the header/footer from mixing up with the content. That lib is a lot of tinkering if you ask me...

Comment: so that's why my tailwind styling is not being applied.

Comment: Have you tried multiple logo? I can only use one base64 logo in browsershot, after that my postman returns 
```
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException

Error Output:
 in file /home/lance/pledgebox/pledgebox_be/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/Browsershot.php on line 953
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  // or a .pdf file
  await page.pdf({
    printBackground: true,
    width: `595px`, // ? 3508 x 2480 (print) || 595 pixels x 842 pixels (screen)
    height: `842px`, // ? Here subraction for making alignment looks cool
    margin: {
      top: '25px',
      bottom: '60px',
      left: '25px',
      right: '25px'
    },
    path: path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'pdf', 'report.pdf'),
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    footerTemplate: `
    <p style="margin: auto;font-size: 13px;">
      <span class="pageNumber"></span>
        /
      <span class="totalPages"></span>
    </p>
    `
  });
```

Hopefully, this one resolved someone's issue with the same problem. The footer was not shown before properly and finally done about a little bit search so comes with the above solution.

> NOTE:
>
> 1. Don't forget to mentioned `margin-bottom: 60px`(atleast).
> 2. Same for `displayHeaderFooter: true`.
> 3. Must needs to specify the `font-size: 10px`(atleast bcze default by `font-size: 0`).

For more info refer to this issue:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1822

Answer (score 0):

if the above code didn't work for you. please try to use marginTop and marginBottom instead of margin object.

```
var buffer = await page.pdf({
         printBackground: true,         
         footerTemplate: "<div style='width: 200px; background-color: #4286f4; position: relative; position: absolute; top:0;'>Hej</div>",
         headerTemplate: "<div style='width: 200px; background-color: #4286f4; position: relative; position: absolute; bottom: 0;'>Footer</div>",
         //displayHeaderFooter: true, 
         marginTop:"100px",
         marginBottom: "100px"
    });
```

notes:
it works for me in nodejs. I use jsreport with recipe "chrome-pdf". The chrome-pdf module using puppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

Here is an example of a function that can add a background:

```
const getHeaderFooter = () => {
   return `<html>
             <style>html {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;} </style>
             <span style="margin: -5em 0 0 0; height: 3mm; z-index: 1000; 
                    background: blue; width: 100%;"/>
          </html>`
}
```

And calling the function:

```
 headerTemplate: getHeaderFooter(),
```

Comment: gonna need more explanation than that.  Why?  How does it work?  Wheres the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

## 2023 Implementation

- Header: 2 columns
- Footer: 1 column with centred text

```
// create a new page  
const page = await browser.newPage();

// set your html as the pages content
await page.setContent(html, {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2' // waits until no more than 2 requests happen within 500ms
});
await page.evaluateHandle('document.fonts.ready');
await page.screenshot();

// create a PDF buffer
await page.pdf(
  {
    format: 'a4',
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    headerTemplate: headerTemplate,
    footerTemplate: footerTemplate,
    margin: { top: 100, bottom: 60 }
  }
);
```

```
const headerTemplate = `<div style="display: inline-block; width: 75%; margin: 0 2cm">
                            <img style="height: 50px;" src="${LogoBase64}" />  
                            <div style="float: right; font-size: 7pt; text-align: right;">${AddressInfo}</div>
                        </div>`
const footerTemplate = `<div style="margin: 0 2cm; width: 75%; font-size: 7px; text-align: center;">${Disclaimer}</div>`;
```

## FINDINGS

- Only use inline styles
- To get all elements to display on the same line use `display: inline-block`
- Position using `float: position`
- Apply `font-size` since the default is `0px`
- RECOMMENDED: minimum margin size is `60`
- RECOMMENDED: page format set to `a4`
- Margin size determines the amount of displayable space for the header and footer

  - NOTE: This does not position the elements
- NOTE: Margin is double the content size

  - image = 50px
  - margin = 100px
  - Not sure how this scales
- Don't use async data

  - image is encoded as base54 instead of the CDN link
- Use `margin` tag to apply additional margins for positioning

Comment: Hi Marc, I used your headerTemplate & footerTemplate approach. However, the solution you provided only seems to work for the first page, where the header is at the top and the footer is at the bottom, without appearing behind the main content. On the subsequent pages, the header and footer are in the correct positions but appear behind the main content.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to add this property to show the header and footer.

```
displayHeaderFooter: true
```